# Discord.js v.12.5.3 embed help bug

Tags: discord.js

The part 'const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()' and 'command(client, 'embed', (message) => {' get wrong but i fail debug
command(client, 'embed', (message) => {
^

ReferenceError: command is not defined
at Client. (D:\DC Bot\discord.js:278:9)
at Client.emit (node:events:532:35)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\DC Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (D:\DC Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (D:\DC Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (D:\DC Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (D:\DC Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (D:\DC Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (D:\DC Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1047:20)

```
`client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === '-rhelp') {
        command(client, 'embed', (message) => {
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('MCMB 指令')
        .addFields(
            { name: '【機器人加入語音】', value: '-rjoin', inline: true },
            { name: '【播放音樂（加入隊列）】', value: '-rplay <音樂網址>', inline: true },
            { name: '【暫停播放】', value: '-rpause', inline: true },
            { name: '【恢復播放】', value: '-rresume', inline: true },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
            { name: '【跳過這首歌曲】', value: '-rskip', inline: true },
            { name: '【查看歌曲隊列】', value: '-rqueue', inline: true },
            { name: '【讓機器人離開語音頻道（會清空歌曲隊列）】', value: '-rleave', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setTimestamp()
    message.channel.send(embed)
    })
    }
});

client.login(token);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined "command". It is not a default feature of Discord.js, you have to make it yourself.